# Permission Denied While Accessing Files in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: windows, python-3.x, anaconda

I have a Python script that accesses some files, form example one line of code appends some text to a .txt file. 
It runs correctly in a normal cmd.exe, with or without Admnistrator access. But while using a Anaconda Prompt or a cmd.exe opened from Anaconda Navigator it gives a `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:` in the `open('path/to/file', 'a+')` line.

I'm looking for a solution for why Anaconda's python cannot access files. Another line of code using the function `handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler()` from the logging module also throws the same error.

Some info that might be useful:

- I have two Anaconda environments, one with python 2.7 and another one with python 3.6.6, both throw the error;
- I have installed Anaconda 3 without adding anaconda to my PATH, because it was recommended in the installer;
- My PATH's python, the version that works in the non-anaconda cmd.exe, is also 3.6.6;
- I use Windows 10.

## Edit:

Okay, so there seems to be some confusion about what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm making a text file with every .jpg file in a folder recursively, followed by the split of the file name. The text file should have: "path/to/XY_file_XY.jpg file" for every file found. Those splits represent the labels of the images for a neural network I'm training.

Here is my code for creating this text file:

```
import glob

class DBSetter(object):
    def __init__(self, rootPath = 'C:\\Users\\Victor.Lundgren\\Google Drive\\Mestrado\\VC\\Projeto\\data\\mnt'):
        self.path = rootPath
        return

    def setDB(self, extension = '.jpg', splitFileName = True, splitDilimiter = '_', splitPosition = 1):
        query = self.path+'\\**\\*'+extension
        print(query)
        fileList = glob.glob(query, recursive = True)
        sampleFileText = ''
        for file in fileList:
            word = file.split('\\')[-1]
            if splitFileName:
                word = word.split(splitDilimiter)[splitPosition]
            sampleFileText += file+' '+word+'\n'
        print('Sample File Text created.')
        sampleFile = open(self.path+'\\sample.txt', 'a+')
        sampleFile.write(sampleFileText)
        sampleFile.close()
        return
```

For instance, let's create a DBSetter object in a **main**.py and test ir with the default Python (3.6.6) in a simple cmd.exe and with Anaconda's Python (3.6.6) in an Anaconda Prompt:

```
from utils import database_setter

setter = database_setter.DBSetter('C:\\Users\\Victor.Lundgren\\Pictures\\Trabalho\\ASA') #choosing this folder for this example because it has few files in it.
setter.setDB(extension = '.png', splitFileName = False)
```

Here we have our cmd history in a simple cmd.exe calling **main**.py:

```
> Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.16299.492] (c) 2017 Microsoft
> Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados. Clink v0.4.9 [git:2fd2c2]
> Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Martin Ridgers http://mridgers.github.io/clink
> 
> 
> C:\Users\Victor.Lundgren>cd C:\Users\Victor.Lundgren\Google Drive\Mestrado\VC\Projeto
> 
> C:\Users\Victor.Lundgren\Google Drive\Mestrado\VC\Projeto>Python
> __main__.py C:\Users\Victor.Lundgren\Pictures\Trabalho\ASA\**\*.png Sample File Text created.
> 
> C:\Users\Victor.Lundgren\Google Drive\Mestrado\VC\Projeto>
```

Now executing Anaconda Promp from the windows menu and runnning the same thing with my Python 3.6.6 env:

```
> Clink v0.4.9 [git:2fd2c2] Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Martin Ridgers
> http://mridgers.github.io/clink
> 
> 
> (base) C:\Users\Victor.Lundgren>cd C:\Users\Victor.Lundgren\Google Drive\Mestrado\VC\Projeto
> 
> (base) C:\Users\Victor.Lundgren\Google Drive\Mestrado\VC\Projeto>activate Py3
> 
> (Py3) C:\Users\Victor.Lundgren\Google Drive\Mestrado\VC\Projeto>Python
> __main__.py C:\Users\Victor.Lundgren\Pictures\Trabalho\ASA\**\*.png Sample File Text created. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
>     setter.setDB(extension = '.png', splitFileName = False)   File "C:\Users\Victor.Lundgren\Google Drive\Mestrado\VC\Projeto\utils\database_setter.py", line 19, in setDB
>     sampleFile = open(self.path+'\\sample.txt', 'a+') PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> 'C:\\Users\\Victor.Lundgren\\Pictures\\Trabalho\\ASA\\sample.txt'
> 
> (Py3) C:\Users\Victor.Lundgren\Google Drive\Mestrado\VC\Projeto>
```

Comment: Trying to open a directory would also raise a permission error in Windows, so first it's important to rule out an incorrect path passed to `open`. We also have to rule out problems with relative paths if the script mistakenly assumes the process working directory is always the script directory. They have nothing inherently to do with each other and are only the same sometimes depending on how the script is run.

Comment: Valid points, I am passing a absolute path to open ('C:\\Users\\Victor.Lundgren\\Pictures\\Trabalho'), and as I noted in the question the same script runs correctly using the default python, so the path exists.

Comment: @eryksun I have pasted the wrong path, the correct one is 'C:\\Users\\Victor.Lundgren\\Pictures\\Trabalho\\sample.txt'. The file is written/created correctly in the default python, so the path **is not** the problem.

Comment: @eryksun My default Python version, as I noted in the question, is 3.6.6. I have an Anaconda env with Python 3.6.6. The default python 3.6.6 runs it, while Anaconda python 3.6.6 doesn't. It makes me think it has nothing to do with the script, but rather with Anaconda's python or anaconda itself not getting permission for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174295/discussion-between-victor-lundgren-and-eryksun).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After multiple attempts on reinstalling Anaconda I discovered the issue. My antivirus (Bitdefender) was exclusively blocking the Python version installed by Anaconda and for some reason not showing any notifications of it being blocked, removing the block made it run correctly.